# Android volley - avoid multiple requests of the same kind to the server?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley to upload a list of images to the server. This happens within a service. Once an image is uploaded I remove it from the list. The problem arises when the internet connection breaks. When the internet connection breaks and comes up again I am thinking of adding the images which are yet to be uploaded back to the request queue.

This can result in more than one copy of the same image saved on the server as a request for the same image might have already gone through before getting the rseponse.

How can I address this scenario?

Comment: Maybe you could calculate hashes for each file which are stored in the servers db, when sending a new set of images compare hashes with the ones in the db, if existend remove from your list of images an start the request ... This is maybe not the best solution, but the first one which was in my mind...

Comment: Yeah I thought of that. But I do not want to change the server code as such. I want to prevent this case from the app itself.

Comment: Okay then what about an event each time one file is successfuly uploaded to the server so you can remember that for the next time. So maybe upload each image from the list seperately und onPostRequest remove the image from the list and continue with the next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you're using a service to schedule the requests as volley automatically runs it's request in a seperate thread.

Nevertheless you can listen to both request results, successful and unsuccessful simply by adding the listeners.

You can remove an image from the list as soon as you schedule a request using volley. If it succeeds you can carry on as desired, if it fails however you can simply add it again back to your list.

```
public static Request getImageUploadRequest(final String image) {
     Response.Listener<T> responseListener = new Response.Listener<T>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(T response) {
                     // do whatever you like
                 }
     };

     Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                     // put the image back onto the list
                     SomeClass.addImageToList(image);
                 }
     };

     return new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, YOUR_URL, null, responseListener, errorListener); // Use any subclass of Request you like
}
```

Comment: But in "onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)" how do I know which is the image that has failed to upload? The "error" argument does not have any such information.

Comment: That's right. However if you first create the request you can pass the argument onto the error listener. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! So this uses the fact that anonymous inner classes can access final local variables right?

Comment: I use a service as I will register a broadcast receiver in the service which can listen to internet connectivity changes and take appropriate actions. I need this to happen even if the app is not open. So a service should serve the purpose I hope?